# Cómo cambiar datos de un CSV ANSI a UTF PHP para insertar en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estoy leyendo un CSV con PHP y me muestra caracteres extraños al leerlo, debido a la codificación ANSI del CSV. Para insertarlo en MySQL, necesito cambiar la codificación a UTF-8. He estado investigando, pero no me ha quedado nada claro como hacerlo. Actualmente, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
require_once "connection-mysql.php";

//ABRO CSV Y LO INSERTO EN LA BBDD

$archivo=fopen("articulos1.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo

while(!feof($archivo)){

    $linea=fgets($archivo); //Leo datos con CSV
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea);

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        var_dump($arrayLineas);
    }
   
 }


   
fclose($archivo);
```

Y esto lo que me muestra:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [1]=>
  string(42) "PORT�TIL ASUS ROG STRIX G15 G512LW-HN069
"
}
```

Cómo podéis observar, en cuánto hay una tilde me muestra caracteres raros. La pregunta exacta es: ¿cómo hago para que me lo lea bien y para poder meterlo en MySQL directamente en UTF-8, a fin de ahorrarme problemas? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye la línea:

```
$linea=fgets($archivo); //Leo datos con CSV
```

Por:

```
$linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV
```

Si con `utf8_encode()` no va, hazlo con `utf8_decode()`.

Con MySQL también tienes la opción de utilizar el método:

```
query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: Ha funcionado con utf8_encode(). Muchas gracias :)